# How do I use a function within the for loop and using whole columns as the argument?

Tags: r

What I want to do is to create a for loop where the entire column of my data is used as the argument in the function. I tried the for loop code. The function I use within the for loop is the MAD function where I hope to find outliers of the four values of each column.

```
outliers<-for(D in NahOstRooi[,1:4]) {D[which((abs(D-median(D))/mad(D)) >2)]}
```

The result I get out of this is `NULL`.

The data looks like that:

```
NahOstRooi <- plotslossfin[,c(2,3,4,63)]

> NahOstRooi
# A tibble: 4 × 4
   RnoSE  RnoSW  RnoNE  RnoNW
   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 0.7480 0.1267 0.6669 0.5484
2 0.8415 0.6157 0.6540 0.8428
3 0.8560 0.5858 0.6071 0.8171
4 0.8034 0.6479 0.6201     NA
```

I kind of fear that I'm completely misusing the for loop. I also tried to do an `=` instead of the `in` within the curved brackets.

Comment: What language is this, R?

Comment: Yes, it is R! :)

Comment: `sapply(df, function(D)D[which((abs(D-median(D))/mad(D)) >2)])`... Also, Median Absolute Deviation - M.A.D. - Best acronym ever :p

Comment: Haha. Yass. I don't even know if it is absolutely mad to use this for four values. but it is only for the purpose of practice ;)

Comment: is this automatic within the sapply function to use columns? And How does it recognize the D?BtW, it works!